# How to implement laravel-echo client into Vue project

Tags: php, laravel, events, vue.js, broadcast

I'm developing an application with **Vuetify** (Vue.js) as front-end that communicates with api to **laravel** backend server.

I'm trying to make a system of notifications with **laravel-echo-server** working with **socket.io**. And using laravel-echo into client too.

The code that I uses into a component of client to test if connection works is:

```
// Needed by laravel-echo
window.io = require('socket.io-client')

let token = this.$store.getters.token

let echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'socket.io',
  host: 'http://localhost:6001',
  auth: {
    headers: {
      authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'too_long_csrf_token_hardcoded'
    }
  }
})

echo.private('Prova').listen('Prova', () => {
  console.log('IT WORKS!')
})
```

This is the code of `laravel-echo-server.json`

```
{
    "authHost": "http://gac-backend.test",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

I tried to modify **apiOriginsAllow** without success.
The event is dispatched, I can see it into **laravel-echo-server** logs:

```
Channel: Prova
Event: App\Events\Prova
```

But after that, when I access into a component of the client that contains the connection code I can see in laravel-echo-server logs long error trace and the next error:

```
The client cannot be authenticated, got HTTP status 419
```

As you can see, I specified csrf token and authorization token into the headers of laravel echo client. But it doesn't work.

This is the code of `routes/channels.php`:

```
Broadcast::channel('Prova', function ($user) {
    return true;
});
```

I only want to listen an event, it doesn't important if it is private or public because when it works, I want to put it into service worker. Then, I suppose that is better if it is public.

- **How can I use laravel echo client out of laravel project?**
- **Will be a problem if I make private event and try to listen it into a service worker?**

Comment: Did you already solve this?
I also want to implement Echo with CORS setup (Laravel backend and Vue Single Page App). But my development even worse than yours. I still don't understand how to catch the returned data from event.
If i check the log (laravel.log file), broadcasting was dispatched successfully with payload, but on frontend it also got errors `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header`. I've setup headers with bearer token but error still appear

Comment: Update, the error already gone when I've setup CORS in the laravel project.
Now, the main problem is same with you, how use laravel echo client outside laravel project :D

Comment: @MuhammadIzzuddinAlFikri I wrote the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52256566/8950695.

Comment: 419 is a CSRF error, using a POST without the "_token" set to Laravel's CSRF. You can put an exception in the VerifyCSRFToken.php in middleware, or change your authentication strategy and use API with Passport or JWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start client listeners i used Vuex. Then, when my application starts I dispatch the action `INIT_CHANNEL_LISTENERS` to start listeners.

**index.js of channels MODULE vuex**

```
import actions from './actions'
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
import getters from './getters'
import mutations from './mutations'

window.io = require('socket.io-client')

export default {
  state: {
    channel_listening: false,
    echo: new Echo({
      broadcaster: 'socket.io',
      // host: 'http://localhost:6001'
      host: process.env.CHANNEL_URL
    }),
    notifiable_public_channels: [
      {
        channel: 'Notificacio',
        event: 'Notificacio'
      },
      {
        channel: 'EstatRepetidor',
        event: 'BroadcastEstatRepetidor'
      }
    ]
  },
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations
}
```

**actions.js of channels MODULE vuex**

```
import * as actions from '../action-types'
import { notifyMe } from '../../helpers'
// import { notifyMe } from '../../helpers'

export default {
  /*
  * S'entent com a notifiable un event que té "títol" i "message" (Per introduir-los a la notificació)
  * */
  /**
   * Inicialitza tots els listeners per als canals. Creat de forma que es pugui ampliar.
   * En cas de voler afegir més canals "Notifiables" s'ha de afegir un registre al state del index.js d'aquest modul.
   * @param context
   */
  [ actions.INIT_CHANNEL_LISTENERS ] (context) {
    console.log('Initializing channel listeners...')
    context.commit('SET_CHANNEL_LISTENING', true)

    context.getters.notifiable_public_channels.forEach(listener => {
      context.dispatch(actions.INIT_PUBLIC_NOTIFIABLE_CHANNEL_LISTENER, listener)
    })
    // }
  },

  /**
   * Inicialitza un event notificable a través d'un canal.
   * Per anar bé hauria de tenir un titol i un missatge.
   * @param context
   * @param listener
   */
  [ actions.INIT_PUBLIC_NOTIFIABLE_CHANNEL_LISTENER ] (context, listener) {
    context.getters.echo.channel(listener.channel).listen(listener.event, payload => {
      notifyMe(payload.message, payload.title)
    })
  }
}
```

**notifyMe function in helpers**
That function dispatches notification on the browser

```
export function notifyMe (message, titol = 'TITLE', icon = icon) {
  if (!('Notification' in window)) {
    console.error('This browser does not support desktop notification')
  } else if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
    let notification = new Notification(titol, {
      icon: icon,
      body: message,
      vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
      data: {
        dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
        primaryKey: 1
      }
    })
  }
```

Then the backend uses laravel-echo-server like the question. Using **redis** to queue events and **supervisor** to start laravel-echo-server at startup of the server.

Comment: I'd same tech stack with yours, backend using laravel-echo-server for websocket, and redis to queue events. Only supervisor that i don't use.
I try your solution but I think I know culprit on my project now. My problem is vue app can't recieve event's payload.
And i think why it's not receive because on my `echo.connector.channels` it still empty, even vuex actions already dispatched. Any clue of this?

Comment: Sorry @MuhammadIzzuddinAlFikri , but I had a lot of difficulties to implement that. I hope to be useful for you, but I can't

Comment: No problem dude, I'd solve my problem :) thanks for the information

Comment: @MuhammadIzzuddinAlFikri im facing the same issue, can you please explain how you solved your problem?

Comment: Where do you specify the token?

Comment: Thanks, man. Was searching for an example on using laravel-echo in stores, and here you are!

Answer (score 2):

Hello i am giving you the whole step how to configure VUE with Laravel and Echo functionality

**Step1** Install laravel first

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 5.4.*
```

**STEP 2** Set Variables change Broadcastserviceprovider

we first need to register the `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider`. Open `config/app.php` and uncomment the following line in the providers array.

```
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider
```

We need to tell Laravel that we are using the Pusher driver in the .env file:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
```

add pusher Class in config/app.php

```
'Pusher' => Pusher\Pusher::class,
```

**STEP 3** Add A Pusher to your laravel project

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```

**STEP 4** Add following to config/broadcasting.php

```
'options' => [
          'cluster' => env('PUSHER_CLUSTER'),
          'encrypted' => true,
      ],
```

**STEP 5** Set Pusher Variable

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=xxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PUSHER_CLUSTER=xx
```

**STEP 6** Install Node

```
npm install
```

**STEP 7**  Installl Pusher js

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
```

**STEP 8** uncommnet Following

```
// resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true
});
```

**STEP 9** Before you create Migration

```
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
// remember to use
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
  Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: A lot of thanks for your answer step by step. But I use, vue into a different project and socket.io. At the moment I solvet it using `channel` function instead of `private` on echo instance. (I used `private` and it wasn't works because the channel is public).

Answer (score 0):

for the socket io

`npm install socket.io --save`

If u got invalid fram header set the auth end point in bootstrap.js as follows

`window.Echo = new Echo({
     authEndpoint : 'http://project/broadcasting/auth',
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '63882dbaf334b78ff949',
     cluster: 'ap2',
     encrypted: true
});`